# All objects are black in the render view port

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, shaders, blend-files

The objects are black in render view port but when I render it I can see the color in the image.
Can anyone please help.
computer info:
iMac
garphic: Radeon Pro 580 8 GB
memory 32 GB DDR4
processor: inter core i7

[image]

Comment: can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Apple computer with an AMD graphics card and an Intel processor... there's your problem - they're having a war! All kidding aside, I can't see your full outliner, but it looks like the lights in your scene are hidden - hidden things will still appear in renders even though they are not visible in the viewport. Click the "closed eye" to the right of to the lights name in the outliner to unhide it, or press Alt+H in the viewport to unhide _everything_.

Comment: There is a white arrow already pointing at the problem in your screenshot... disabled lights.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the Lights collection(on the Eye icon) to see them in the rendered view.

[image: Add Lights]